# Bug when trying to update an HTML table value in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to implement a simple update functionality for the values in my table. I have an edit button, which triggers a modal where I edit the values and save them. In order the values to be immediately update in the DOM I am using the following jquery code `on save`:

```
 $('#lblEditDeleteProducts').find("tr .nameDom").text("new val");
 $('#lblEditDeleteProducts').find("tr .brandDom").text("new val");
 $('#lblEditDeleteProducts').find("tr .priceDom").text("new val");
```

**The problem** is that with this code intead of one row in my table all the rows get updated with the "new value". I am very new to jquery and I am out of ideas how to solve this, so any help will be appreciated.

Here is my table structure :

[image]

Comment: It finds any element with the class `.nameDom` inside a TR inside your table etc.

Comment: You need to know the specific row you are "editing", is your button in the row?  $('#lblEditDeleteProducts').find("tr .nameDom") currently returns all of the nameDom cells.

Comment: where is your edit button and how the modal is associated with any particular row?

Comment: @Steve the button which is triggering this event is in a modal, it is not in the row.

Comment: The eddit button is on each row. The eddit button in my case triggers the modal. And when clicked the save button in the modal is supposed to update the values in the dom.

Comment: can you provide the rest of your code

Comment: If the edit button is in each row, we'll need to see it in the HTML you provided.

Comment: It is in the <th> tags.

Comment: I am not seeing the `edit` button in each row

Comment: It is in the <th> tags. But the edit button in this case is not important i think. The save button is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is not much information of your HTML code

```
var selectedTR;

$("#lblEditDeleteProducts tr").click(function(){
    selectedTR=$(this);
    //init your modal pop up here or do it globally
})
```

Let assume the **ID** of save button is **#save**

```
$("#save").click(function(){
 selectedTR.find(".nameDom").text("new val"); // get relative value from the mdoal input
 selectedTR.find(".brandDom").text("new val");
 selectedTR.find(".priceDom").text("new val");
})
```

If you are interested you can use this plugin also (advanced feature) [datatable inline edit](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple)

Comment: Using a similar approach i was able to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The selectors that `find` is using are too general, so they're selecting all matching rows.

```
$('#lblEditDeleteProducts').find("tr .nameDom").text("new val");
```

Here's what jQuery is doing with that particular line of code (the same thing applies to all the others, too):

- Get `lblEditDeleteProducts` by ID
- Using that node, `find()` all descendant elements that match the selector `tr .nameDom`
- Update the text of all nodes that it finds.

In your case, that selector matches every element in every row because they're all descendants of `#lblEditDeleteProducts`; there's no way to filter out just those you want with the code that you've written.

You'll need a way of explicitly determining which row to update.

Comment: Well, I am never updating the ID of my records in the table (it is readonly), so I guess that might be my unique element.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that the edit button is in the each row, you can reference the corresponding row with [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$("EDIT BUTTON SELECTOR").click(function(){
    var $btn = $(this);
    var $row = $btn.closest("tr");
    $("DIALOG SELECTOR").dialog({
         buttons:{
            Save: function(){
                    //bunch of stuff
                    $row.find("td.nameDom").text("new val");
            }
         }
    });
});
```